# I want to root my tablet but cannot

Tags: root-access, tablet

I have a samsung tablet that is entitled samsung tab 4 t-351. I wish to root it, but can find nothing. I have tried towelroot, framaroot, one click,root master, king root , vroot,iroot, and poot

Comment: Try searching for your specific device's root, like "root galaxy tab 4". There certainly are guides on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The model you specified (**T351**) doesn't seem to exist, so I am just going to assume you have the **T531.**

A quick Google search for `samsung galaxy tab 4 root t531` yields an [XDA page](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tab-4/help/sm-t531-14-06-root-t2840991) of someone wanting to root the same model as yours and has had success with [CF-Auto-Root.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=52846251&highlight=sm-t531#post52846251)

Worth a try, since Chainfire's works are pretty much dependable.